# issue in importing quandl in on jupyter notebook

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, quandl

I am trying to import `quandl` on jupyter notebook.

I am using `anaconda 4.4.0` & `python 3.6.1`.

Any suggestion to make it work?

[image]

Comment: Did you install quandl? Also, please do not post code and error messages in images. Search engines cannot index the text (which means no one else can find this question if they have the same error) and blind users cannot read the problem at all.